# Anonymous function on visitObject?

Tags: apollo-server

Right now when a user 'visitFieldDefinition's, I do a bit of computation in the field.resolve function. Is there a way to do this at the visitObject level?

e.g. I update a time value in my database whenever a user visits a field. One query on the object level might trigger that processing several hundred times which is completely redundant. Is there some analogous field.resolve function at the visitObject level?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete, reproducible code.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a schema directive with `OBJECT` as a target that iterates through that object's fields and modifies each field's resolver. However, the resolver logic is always at the field level because only fields are resolved. If the logic you're repeating is independent of the arguments passed to the resolver, then it can reside inside the `visitObject`, otherwise it needs to be inside the resolver function itself.

If the work you're doing inside the resolver is redundant, then you can probably cache whatever value you're repeatedly calculating. The cache can be a variable inside your directive class (in which case it will only be cleared when the process is restarted) or it can be injected into the context (in which case it will be request-specific and be destroyed after your request completes).